# Error opening MDriven EcoSpace or PMP component designers in Visual Studio .NET Standard project

Tags: visual-studio, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, mdriven

I created a new .netstandard2.0 MDrivenEcoSpaceAndModelForNetStandard2 project.  When it is created, I am not able to open the ecospace or the PMP component designers.  I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.8.4 and MDriven Framework version 7.0.0.12868.  I get the following error when opening the PMP.  (BTW, Thanks, I am very happy to see the support for .net standard.  Looking forward to getting this component designer issue figured out and everything working again.  It's been a very long road converting all my projects over to .net standard/core).  Any help is greatly appreciated.

"Unsupported type argument in custom attribute signature."

Instances of this error (1)

Call Stack

at Microsoft.MetadataReader.SignatureUtil.GetTypeId(Type type)
at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyModule.GetConstructorArguments(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, Byte[] customAttributeBlob, Int32& index)
at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyModule.LazyAttributeParse(Token token, ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, IList`1& constructorArguments, IList`1& namedArguments)
at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyCustomAttributeData.InitArgumentData()
at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyCustomAttributeData.get_ConstructorArguments()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.ConstructAttribute(CustomAttributeData data)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.GetCustomAttributes(ICustomAttributesDataProvider member, Type filter, CustomAttributesCache cache)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.GetCustomAttributes(Type type, Type filter, Boolean inherit, CustomAttributesCache cache)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkType.GetCustomAttributes(Type filter, Boolean inherit)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkAttributeCollection.GetAttributes(Type type, Type filter)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkAttributeCollection.GetAttributes(MemberInfo member, Type filter)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkAttributeCollection.get_Attributes()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.EnsureExtensions(IComponent component)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.CreateInstance(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

Slightly different call stack when opening the ecospace:

Instances of this error (1)

Call Stack

at Microsoft.MetadataReader.SignatureUtil.GetTypeId(Type type)
at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyModule.GetConstructorArguments(ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, Byte[] customAttributeBlob, Int32& index)
at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyModule.LazyAttributeParse(Token token, ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, IList`1& constructorArguments, IList`1& namedArguments)
at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyCustomAttributeData.InitArgumentData()
at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyCustomAttributeData.get_ConstructorArguments()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.ConstructAttribute(CustomAttributeData data)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.GetCustomAttributes(ICustomAttributesDataProvider member, Type filter, CustomAttributesCache cache)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.GetCustomAttributes(Type type, Type filter, Boolean inherit, CustomAttributesCache cache)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkType.GetCustomAttributes(Type filter, Boolean inherit)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkAttributeCollection.GetAttributes(Type type, Type filter)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkAttributeCollection.GetAttributes(MemberInfo member, Type filter)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkAttributeCollection.get_Attributes()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.EnsureExtensions(IComponent component)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.CreateInstance(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

[image: PMP Error]

[image: EcoSpace Error]

Answer (score 0):

MDriven had real issues with the new project file format. It behaves very differently in our CodeGen and Save extensions for Visual Studio.

This is however now improved and we think all is fine from version 7.0.0.12950 and onwards.

When it comes to open designer for EcoSpace and PMP we still have issues - but it seems we are not alone since the same issues shows when trying to open a winforms designer. We will need to see how Visual Studio future release handles this.

Workaround is to link the files to a .netFramework project and edit them there - but compile them in .netstandard/core